# What is the utility of allowing unbound types to be referenced in the typeof expression?

Tags: c#, generics

Given

```
        int foo = 1;
        Type unboundType = typeof(List<>);
        Type w = unboundType.MakeGenericType(typeof(int));

        if (w == typeof(List<int>))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes its a List<int>");

            try
            {
                ((List<int>)(object)w).Add(foo);
            }
            catch(InvalidCastException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No you can't cast Type");
            }
        }
```

I can verify that the type indeed matches a constructed type and perform an action based on said constructed type. However, I cannot cast `Type` to it's `class` using `as` or an explicit cast.  Is there a practical purpose for allowing developers to create a `Type` of unbound type or does this functionality exist solely to support the language in some way?

Comment: Are you trying to cast an instance of `System.Type` to an actual `List<int>`? That definitely won't work! You need to instantiate an instance of it _somewhere_; I don't see that in the code you posted.

Comment: As Chris said, `w` is *metadata* about a type. It is not an *instance* of the type. You are not using it correctly here.

Comment: At a high level, that makes sense.  I'm still unclear as to how this information allows me to do anything useful.  I am unable to declare a new object using `w` as my type and I see no method available to "Create instance" if you will.  So a more thorough explanation would help.

Comment: You're not thinking reflectively. ;) You wouldn't typically use this if you were trying to use strong types in code at compile-time. You would use this if trying to discern and deal with dynamic data at runtime, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not everything can be done at compile time. Sometimes, particularly in library code, you need to take what you are given. In scenarios where you are given just an `object` or a `Type` and need to do some clever processing, unbound types can be really helpful; for example:

```
object obj = NoIdeaWhatThisReturns();
IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(
                 typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(obj.GetType()));
list.Add(obj);
```

Basically; scenarios that use a lot of reflection or meta-programming will probably find themselves using unbound types at some point.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  Thanks for seeing through my bad example and getting to the core of the issue.

Answer (score 4):

In the code you posted, you didn't actually *instantiate* an object of that type anywhere. You were simply trying to cast an instance of `System.Type` to `List<int>` which doesn't make sense. If you update your code to actually create an instance, it works:

```
int foo = 1;
Type unboundType = typeof(List<>);
Type w = unboundType.MakeGenericType(typeof(int));

if (w == typeof(List<int>))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yes its a List<int>");
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(w);

    try
    {
        ((List<int>)obj).Add(foo);
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
    }
    catch(InvalidCastException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No you can't cast Type");
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm just missing the crux of your question. Certainly depending on your logic, you could have if/else checks based on some type you don't know at compile time (in your example, you *know* you're working with `int`, but perhaps at runtime that could be other types as desired)

EDIT: Just to provide an example of a truly runtime usage, consider the following:

```
public object CreateList(Type elementType, object initialValue)
{
    if (!elementType.IsAssignableFrom(initialValue.GetType()))
        throw new ArgumentException("Incompatible types!");

    Type unboundType = typeof(List<>);
    Type listType = unboundType.MakeGenericType(elementType);
    object list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
    var addMethod = listType.GetMethod("Add");
    addMethod.Invoke(list, new []{initialValue});
    return list;
}
```

This lets us create a `List<T>` out of some unknown type/object at runtime. Some usage:

```
object intList = CreateList(typeof(int), 1);
object stringList = CreateList(typeof(string), "asdf");

object objectFromSomewhere = GetMyUnknownObject();
object someUnknownListType = CreateList(objectFromSomewhere.GetType(), objectFromSomewhere);
```

So, you might not be able to do *much* with the objects as are; probably could have treated them as `IEnumerable` at least. But that's up to what your system needs to do.

EDIT: Forgot about the `IList` interface:

```
public IList CreateList(Type elementType, object initialValue)
{
    if (!elementType.IsAssignableFrom(initialValue.GetType()))
        throw new ArgumentException("Incompatible types!");

    Type unboundType = typeof(List<>);
    Type listType = unboundType.MakeGenericType(elementType);
    IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
    list.Add(initialValue);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Type` is not a placeholder for a given type - it's a specific type itself to describe other types. There's no point in trying cast it to a different, unrelated type because metadata (obviously) cannot act for that specific type.

The metadata types are used to inspect the various aspects of specific types, not to create one. If you want to create instances of types in a generic way, you can use the `Activator` class for that.

```
Type oType = ...; // get a Type instance here about a type
object[] oArgs = { oParam1, oParam2 }; // constructor parameters (if any)

return ( Activator.CreateInstance ( oType, oArgs ) );
```

This gives you the ability to create types based on strings, for example. You can get a `Type` instance for `System.String` (or from a function call like `GetTypeNameFromUser(...)`) and then create an instance of that type. (`Activator` has direct support for just taking a string but internally, it uses `Type` to look up the type that needs to be instantiated.)

Since all types are equal, you can create a `Type` instance for an unbound generic type just like any other type - at the very least, it allows you to inspect its properties and methods. (As the accepted answer shows, you can also use the `Type` instance to create specialized generic types using `MakeGenericType`.)

Comment: @KirkWoll It does - the last sentence mentions the ability to create `Type` for one to inspect it. I didn't cover trying to create an instance of one.

Comment: @KirkWoll Yes, I agree with you that `MakeGenericType` is important. I did forget to mention that but it was already present in a different answer and I don't like copying from other answers.

Comment: @KirkWoll Updated my answer after your comment. Thank you.